# How to add custom button which opens popup for doing task in jTable jquery plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I am trying to use jTable jquery plugin for showing gridview like control in my asp.net mvc 4 web page. I am new to using jTable and want to use it for CRUD operation also want to create another custom button which opens popup with some form fields which do some task. I go through jTable documentation and find that we can display custom HTML using it's "display" function but how do I show popup containing fields that I want and send AJAX request(as there are only 4 actions show in documentation).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in JSON properties itself :

```
CustomAction: {
    title: '',
    width: '1%',
    sorting: false,
    create: false,
    edit: false,
    list: true,
    display: function (data) {
        if (data.record) {
            return '<button title="Edit Record" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button" onclick="alert(' + data.record.TicketId + '); return false;"><span>Edit Record</span></button>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you let me know what is TicketId